# how read native contacts in android (2.0.1 and above) programmatically?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, synchronization, android-contacts

I want to read native contacts i.e., all the numbers mobile,home,work, others. How to do this using android 2.0.1 ?

Comment: You should find your answer [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3864166/1964177

Comment: check android demos.. http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Apply this..You will get it.

```
    public void readContacts()
{

         ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

         Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);


         if (cur.getCount() > 0)
 {

            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
{

                    System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                    // get the phone number
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                           new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                          String phone = pCur.getString(
                                 pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                          System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                    }
                    pCur.close();


                    // get email and type

                   Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                        // This would allow you get several email addresses
                            // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                        String email = emailCur.getString(
                                      emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                                      emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                      System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                    }
                    emailCur.close();

                    // Get note.......
                    String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] noteWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                            Cursor noteCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, noteWhere, noteWhereParams, null);
                    if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        String note = noteCur.getString(noteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
                      System.out.println("Note " + note);
                    }
                    noteCur.close();

                    //Get Postal Address....

                    String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                    Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, null, null, null);
                    while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String poBox = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
                        String street = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                        String city = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
                        String state = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                        String postalCode = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                        String country = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
                        String type = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));

                        // Do something with these....

                    }
                    addrCur.close();

                    // Get Instant Messenger.........
                    String imWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] imWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                    Cursor imCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, imWhere, imWhereParams, null);
                    if (imCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        String imName = imCur.getString(
                                 imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
                        String imType;
                        imType = imCur.getString(
                                 imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));
                    }
                    imCur.close();

                    // Get Organizations.........

                    String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                    Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
                    if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
                        String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
                    }
                    orgCur.close();
                }
            }
       }
    }

}
```